# Compiling COM object from matlab to use in VB

Tags: dll, vbscript, com, matlab-compiler

I am trying to compile a MatLab app as a COM object to be used in a VB app. (I just one some classes and their methods).
I have no problem during the compiling of the classes and the generation of the *.dll (MatLab compiler gives me not error)... but when I tried to use the class in my VB app I cannot find all the method defined in my class in MatLab neither the properties. 
My Classes are defined like this:

```
classdef class < superclass
  properties
    PropertieA
    PropertieB
  end
  methods
   function method1(x1,x2,x3)
   funtion method2 (x4,x5,x6)
  end
end
```

Someone knows if the compiling process of classes defined as mine compiles all the methods defined inside the class? In case it is possible what else should I do during the compiling process?

Thank you very much

Example Code

```
classdef TimeBasedData < TimeData
properties
    timeformat = 'HH:MM:SS';
end
methods
    function obj = importothercsv(obj,filename)
        try
            obj = importothercsv@data (obj,filename);
            ndataset = obj.nDataset;
            tind = obj.findChannels(ndataset,'time');
            if ~tind
                tind = 1;
            end
            time = obj.Dataset(ndataset,tind).data;
            if isempty(obj.timeformat)
                obj.Dataset(ndataset,tind).data = datenum(time);
            else
                obj.Dataset(ndataset,tind).data = datenum(time,obj.timeformat);
            end
            tdserial = abs(obj.Dataset(ndataset,tindex).data(round(end/2)) - ...
                obj.Dataset(ndataset,tindex).data((round(end/2))+1));
            [~,~,~,~,~,obj.Dataset(ndataset,1).SamplingTime] = datevec(datestr(tdserial,obj.timeformat),obj.timeformat);
        catch exception
            error(exception.message)
        end
    end
      function obj = addChannel(obj,index,name,unit,datavect)
             obj.Dataset(index,obj.Dataset(index,1).nchannels+1).channel = name;
             obj.Dataset(index,obj.Dataset(index,1).nchannels+1).unit = unit;
             obj.Dataset(index,obj.Dataset(index,1).nchannels+1).data = datavect;
             obj.Dataset(index,obj.Dataset(index,1).nchannels+1).DataLength = length(datavect);
             obj.Dataset(index,obj.Dataset(index,1).nchannels+1).SamplingTime = obj.Dataset(index,1).SamplingTime;
             obj.Dataset(index,1).nchannels = obj.Dataset(index,1).nchannels+1;
    end
end
```

end

Comment: Hmya, not that likely that a "funtion" is going to work well.  Posting a completely fake code snippet and documenting it with a very vague "it doesn't work" complaint is unlikely to get you any help here.

Comment: @HansPassant... is a fake code because the app contains around 40 classes defined like the "fake" previous one. Not just one.... but here one so that you understand better...